# É correto limpar um malloc interno a uma função com a mesma?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, gerenciamento-de-memória

Bem dado o código a seguir é fácil fazer o gerenciamento de memória:

**Código Exemplo (em C):**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int *criarValor(void){

   int *valor  = malloc(sizeof *valor);

   *valor = 10;

   return valor;
}

int main(void)
{
   int *valorPtr;

   valorPtr = criarValor();

   /* Usa um ponteiro para acessar os valores */
   printf("O valor na heap é: %d\n", *valorPtr); 

   /* Libera memória alocada */
   free(valorPtr);

   return 0;
}
```

Mas se for feito o dereferenciamento através da própria função? É possível (e/ou necessário) dar free na função? Segue o exemplo de como seria tal caso:

**Caso dúvida (em C):**

```
int *criarValor(void){

   int *valor  = malloc(sizeof *valor);

   *valor = 10;

   return valor;
}

int main(void)
{
   /* Usa a própria função dereferenciada para acessar os valores */
   printf("O valor na heap é: %d\n", *criarValor()); 

   /* É correto dar esse free? A memória alocada 
      é corretamente liberada? */
   free(criarValor());

   return 0;
}
```

A dúvida prossegue em C++:

**Código dúvida (em C++):**

```
#include <iostream>

int *criarValor(void){

   int *valor  = new int(10);

   return valor;
}

int main()
{ 
   // Usa a própria função dereferenciada para acessar os valores
   std::cout << "O valor no heap é : " << *criarValor() << std::endl;

   // É correto dar esse deletada? A memória alocada 
   // é corretamente liberada?
   delete criarValor();
}
```

A memória alocada está sendo liberada de forma correta?

Comment: Nos dois últimos exemplos, você aloca dois valores, mas só libera um.

Comment: Como assim aloco dois valores? Eu só criei uma região de memória em que cabe um inteiro.

Comment: Cada chamada da função faz uma alocação distinta, não?

Comment: A dúvida é a segunda chamada, justamente no `free (delete)`.

Comment: Olha, eu sou fraco em C e absolutamente ignorante em C++, mas no meu entender o seu free só libera a memória que acabou de ser alocada na chamada que tem ali dentro. A chamada dentro do printf fez outra alocação, e você não tem como liberar essa memória porque não guardou o ponteiro retornado na primeira chamada.

Comment: Essa é a dúvida.

Comment: Acho que a questão aí é que cada chamada de malloc vai alocar uma nova área de memória, sendo assim no seu código a linha "free(criarValor());" vai liberar a memória alocada pela chamada a criaValor que está dentro da chamada a free e não a memória alocada anteriormente por "printf("O valor na heap é: %d\n", *criarValor());",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mas se for feito o dereferenciamento através da própria função?

Quando você faz `free(foo())`, você não está fazendo o free "através de foo". Você está simplesmente dando free no valor de retorno de foo(). É como se você tivesse feito

```
 int *tmp = foo();
 free(tmp);
```

Similarmente, no seu printif você não está "usando a prória função dereferenciada", você está dereferenciando o ponteiro retornado pela função.

Uma maneira fácil de ver isso é botar um printf dentro do `criarValor`. Vai dar pra ver que você está rodando a função duas vezes.

Em C a melhor coisa que você pode fazer é escrever o programa como no seu primeiro exemplo mesmo. [Se você não botar a declaração do ponteiro separado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474100/where-you-can-and-cannot-declare-new-variables-in-c/8474123#8474123) nem fica tão ruim:

```
int main(void)
{
   int *valorPtr = criarValor();

   /* Usa um ponteiro para acessar os valores */
   printf("O valor na heap é: %d\n", *valorPtr); 

   /* Libera memória alocada */
   free(valorPtr);

   return 0;
}
```

Se o seu problema for que o meio do código tem mais de um ponto de saída, use goto:

```
int main(void)
{
   int *valorPtr = criarValor();

   if(valor == 17){
      /* Erro, abortar */
      goto cleanup;
   }else{
      printf("O valor na heap é: %d\n", *valorPtr); 
   }

  cleanup:
   free(valorPtr);

   return 0;
}
```

Já em C++ você tem mais uma opção. Objetos rodam seus destrutores assim que eles saem do escopo e você pode botar o delete dentro desses destrutores.

Por exemplo, você pode botar o seu ponteiro dentro de um [ponteiro inteligente](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponteiro_inteligente). Nas versões mais modernas de C++ eles fazem parte da biblioteca padrão.

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
   std::unique_ptr<int> valorPtr(criarValor());

   std::cout << "O valor no heap é : " << *valorPtr << std::endl;

   // Assim que essa função retorna e valorPtr sai do escopo,
   // o destrutor do unique_ptr roda e dá delete no conteúdo.
   return 0;
}
```